# Select from 2 Arrays in a Foreach

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

`$foo` has a list of 50 userids.

```
$foo | foreach {
  Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity ($_.alias + ":\calendar") 
} | select user,accessrights
```

How can I select the userid in `$foo` and then also have `user`, `accessrights` in the same line?  The resulting command above just lists out the user and accessrights to the userid in `$foo`, but never the actual userid, so I can't tell which userid matches up to which user and the accessrights to that userid's calendar.

Answer (score 2):

Use a proper `foreach` loop and use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to grab the user id inside the loop:

```
foreach($id in $foo) 
{
    Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity ($id.alias + ":\calendar") | Select-Object User,AccessRights,@{Name='UserID';Expression={$id}}
}
```

The reason for using a `foreach` loop rather than the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet, is that `$_` inside the `Select-Object` expression block no longer refers to the original `$foo` element, but to the current item piped in from `Get-MailboxFolderPermission`. By having the current `$foo` element be a named variable (`$id`) inside the entire loop body, we can still refer to it from `Select-Object`.